# Storing OpenGL state

Tags: c++, opengl

Suppose I'm trying to make some kind of a small opengl graphics engine on C++. I've read that accessing opengl state via `glGet*` functions can be quite expensive (while accessing opengl state seems to be an often operation), and it's strongly recommended to store a copy of opengl state somewhere with fast read/write access.

I'm currently thinking of storing the opengl state as a global thread_local variable of some appropriate type. How bad is that design? Are there any pitfalls?

Comment: You don't want thread-local storage for this. The state machine is per-render context, so write a thin wrapper for your render context and call it a day. You can add as much or as little sophistication to the state manipulation in your wrapper as you want. The only thread-local storage you might want is a variable to keep track of which context is active in the current thread, and even that is overkill because all of the window system APIs have a function you can call for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only (reasonably) use a GL context with one thread, why do you need thread local? Yes, you can make a context current in different threads at different times, but this is not a wise design.

You will usually have one context and one thread accessing it. In rare cases, you will have two contexts (often shared) with two threads. In that case, you can simply put any additional state you wish to save into your context class, of which each instance is owned by exactly one thread.

But most of the time, you need not explicitly "remember" states anyway. All states have well-documented initial states, and they only change when *you* change them (exception being changes made by a "super smart" toolkit, but storing a *wrong* state doesn't help in that case either).

You will usually try to batch together states and do many "similar" draw calls with one set of states, the reason being that state changes are stalling the pipeline and need expensive validations being done before the next draw calls.
So, start off with the defaults, and set everything that needs to be non-default before drawing a batch. Then change what needs to be different for the next batch.

If you can't be bothered to dig through the specs for default values and keep track, you can redundantly set everything all the time. Then run your application in GDebugger, which will tell you what state changes are redundant, so you can elimiate them.

Comment: "of which each instance is owned by exactly one thread."

This is why it should be thread_local, isn't it?

Comment: I don't have experience with "real" 3D engines but this seems a bit optimistic... Either you re-set every state back to the default after using it (waste of time and possibly doubly so because you might re-apply that same state for the next drawing calling) *or* you assume to know the OpenGL state for any point in your code. How do you go about that if you don't want a single huge "render" function?

Comment: @lisyarus: The context is "magically thread-local" by itself. The thread that created the context owns it, unless a different one calls `MakeCurrent`. Any other calls from another thread will fail. Making a context current to another thread is an abhorrently slow function, though. So although possible, _practically_, you can only use one context with one thread. If only one thread accesses the context anyway, there's little to gain from making every bit of information thread-local.

Comment: @Damon: I know that the opengl context is thread-local by itself. I'm talking about making the stored opengl state thread-local, so that the real stored state can be accessed only by the thread that owns the context. After some consideration, I realise that this way every thread will have a copy of an opengl state, while only one thread will be working with opengl, so making it thread-local is probably a bad design.

Comment: @heinrichj: It depends, but usually you don't really change **that** much state all the time. In a "real" 3D engine as you call it, people often put everything into a container together with a "key" that discriminates by render pass and importance of state change, sort, and draw the sorted commands in order. Others just do that thing by hand, for example draw your terrain, then all houses, then all trees (instanced), and then e.g. animated characters. The groups of things you draw are all still very similar in state (maybe a texture is different, but that's pretty much it).

Comment: @lisyarus: Right. The point is that only one thread can _meaningfully_ use that data anyway. If it's on that thread's stack, it's "thread local" anyway, and if it's allocated on the heap, the other threads likely don't know about it either (unless you pass them a pointer), but if they know, they can't do anything meaningful with it anyway. Insofar the whole "thread local" stuff is a bit superfluous. It's a private copy of data which doesn't make any sense to anyone but the original owner. It's not strictly _wrong_, but it gives no benefit.

Comment: @Damon: I didn't get the idea with keys and sorting, could you say more about it or give some sources where to read about it?

Comment: @Damon: OpenGL contexts are **not** owned by the thread that created it. It's perfectly possible, and common practice to migrate OpenGL contexts between threads. In the same way it's possible to use a single OpenGL context for multiple windows.

Comment: @datenwolf: You did read the second half of the sentence, didn't you? A context is certainly current (the equivalent of "owned") in the thread that created it, unless and until you explicitly do something about it by calling `[glx|wgl]MakeCurrent`.

Comment: Opps, I did miss the second half. Anyway, "owned" is a too harsh word to use there; it implies that it can not be reassigned. "Bound" is IMHO a better word for what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with OpenGL's design (where your context pointer could be considered "thread_local") I guess it's a valid option... Obviously, you will need to have full control over all OpenGL calls in order to keep your state copy in sync with the current context's state.

I personally prefer to wrap the OpenGL state of interest using an "OpenGLState" class with a bunch of settable/gettable properties each mapping to some part of the state. You can then also avoid setting the same state twice. You could make it thread_local, but I couldn't (Visual C++ only supports thread_local for POD types).

You will need to be very careful, as some OpenGL calls indirectly change seemingly unrelated parts of the context's state. For example, glDeleteTextures will reset any binding of the deleted texture(s) to 0. Also, some toolkits are very "helpful" in changing OpenGL state behind your back (for example, QtOpenGLContext on OSX changes your viewport for you when made current).

Comment: I understand that the opengl state changes not so obviously and that I'll have to read the documentation really carefully :)

Comment: almost makes you want to create a shadowing layer