# Should I cache OpenGL state such as currently bound buffers, or does OpenGL do that anyway?

Tags: c++, opengl

A typical OpenGL call might look like the following:

```
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_SOME_BUFFER, buffer);
...
```

I've read that binding of buffers and other similar functions can be quite expensive. Is it worth saving the currently bound buffer, and checking it before I bind? Such as this:

```
void StateManager::bindBuffer(GLenum bufType, GLuint bufID) {
    if (this->m_currentBuffer[bufType] != bufID) {
        glBindBuffer(bufType, bufID);
        this->m_currentBuffer[bufType] = bufID;
    }
}
```

The idea behind this being that if `bufID` is already bound then the expensive call to `glBindBuffer` is missed. Is this a worthwhile approach? I assumed that OpenGL would likely implement such an optimization already, but I have seen this pattern used in a few projects now, so I am having my doubts. I am simply interested because it would be a pretty simple thing to implement, but if it doesn't make much/any difference then I will skip it (avoiding premature optimization).

Comment: If you're going to implement this, you should implement it *correctly*. There is no single "current buffer"; each `bufType` has *its own* current buffer.

Comment: Of course, but the idea still stands. I will edit the post, though.

Comment: Once I asked a similar question. Not quite satisfied by the answers, though, so not marking as a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094960/storing-opengl-state

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but [this article](https://books.google.at/books?id=ujfOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=cozzi+delaying+opengl+calls&source=bl&ots=OB5P2vjh3a&sig=4e6cZHpA4JLXTbt5rh6zmd_CtOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuwfbxgLjOAhVD2BoKHeN5BLoQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=cozzi%20delaying%20opengl%20calls&f=false) might be interesting to read

Comment: @BDL thank you, that was interesting.

Comment: Personally I'd be very surprised if the driver didn't do this *where it was faster to do so* because if it's 1% faster by doing this check on average then they are 1% faster their competition now than they would other wise have been. It's such an easy quick performance win... And if it's not, then you won't see much advantage doing it either.

Comment: It's useful for software testing. I do a lot of API hooking for software I did not write and have to be very anal about keeping the state machine in a consistent state. I have never seen major benefits from doing this, bigger benefits come from checking not for particular binding states but for redundant data modification. I've written code to checksum all of the data passing through `glTexImage2D (...)` and avoid CPU->driver->GPU work when there's already a valid texture with the same data. That offers huge performance improvements in GL and D3D, I'm not sure why driver vendors don't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is highly platform and vendor dependent.

You're asking if "OpenGL would implement...". As you certainly understand already, OpenGL is an API specification. There are many different implementations, and whether they check for redundant state changes is entirely an implementation decision, which can (and will) be different from implementation to implementation.

You shouldn't even expect that a given implementation handles this the same for all pieces of state.

Since this topic is somewhat close to my heart based on past experience, I was tempted to write a small essay, including a few rants. But I decided that it wouldn't belong here, so here is just a list of considerations that could affect if a given OpenGL implementation tests for redundant state changes in specific cases:

- How expensive is it to actually change the state? If it's very cheap, checking for redundant changes might simply not be worth it.
- How expensive is it to check for redundant changes? Normally not much, but we're looking at pieces of software where every little bit counts.
- Are important apps/benchmarks redundantly changing this state on a frequent basis?
- What's the philosophy on responsibilities of apps vs. responsibilities of OpenGL implementations?

And yes, this is unfortunate for everybody. For you as an app writer who wants to get ideal performance across vendors/platforms, there's really no easy solution. If you add checks to your code, they will be useless, and add extra overhead, on platforms that have the same checks in the OpenGL implementation. If you do not have checks in your code, and cannot easily avoid having these redundant state changes in the first place, you may leave performance on the table on platforms where the OpenGL implementation does not check.

Comment: I see. This is prety much what I suspected. Out of interest, do you know if either DirectX or Vulkan suffer from similar problems? I assume they must, due to the implementation specificness.

Comment: @user3183526: Vulkan is low-level. If you bind some state to a command buffer, then you should expect to incur the costs of binding it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why state caching is a bad idea is simple: you're doing it wrong. You'll *always* be in danger of doing it wrong.

Oh sure, you corrected the mistake I pointed out, that different buffer bindings have different state. And maybe you're using a hash-table that makes lookup pretty quick, even if a new extension comes out that [adds a new buffer binding point](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/indirect_parameters.txt) that didn't exist when you wrote your cache.

But that's merely the tip of the iceberg as far as object binding idiosyncrasies.

For example, did you realize that `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not actually context state? It's really *VAO state*, and every time you bind a new VAO, that buffer binding changes. So your VAO cache now has to change the shadowed element buffer binding too.

Also, were you aware that deleting an object automatically *unbinds* it from any context binding points it is currently bound to? And this is true even for objects that are attached to another object that is bound to the context; the deleted object is automatically detached.

Except that this is only true for *certain object types*. And even then, it's only true for the context that was *current* when the object was deleted. Other contexts will be unaffected.

My point is this: proper caching of state is *really hard.* And if you get it wrong, you will create a multitude of very subtle bugs in your application. Whereas if you just let OpenGL do its thing and structure your code so that multiple binding simply doesn't happen, then you don't have a problem.

Comment: I see. But the currently bound `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` automatically binds when a different `vao` gets bound, correct? So in that case you aren't getting any speed boost, but you aren't getting any bugs. In the second example, would it not be possible just to set the current cache setting to an invalid number (e.g `0` for buffers) when something gets deleted so that the next object gets bound regardless. And either way, if that doesn't happen for a specified buffer type, then at the worst you are binding it a couple more times than you should, which is not much of a problem, no?

Comment: @user3183526: "*So in that case you aren't getting any speed boost, but you aren't getting any bugs.*" Let's say you bind buffer A while VAO Q is bound. Then you switch to VAO R which uses buffer B. And then you try to bind buffer A. Well, your cache thinks that A is *already bound* and therefore doesn't bind it again. Which means that VAO R is still using buffer B when you wanted to change it to use buffer A.

Comment: "*would it not be possible just to set ... when something gets deleted*" You could do that. But my overall point is this: were you even aware of this problem *before* I mentioned it? How can you be certain that you have discovered all of these kinds of issues? And if you're not *certain*, then it isn't reliable. Broken code is worse than slow-performing code.